# Hom sheaf of a torsion sheaf

Tags: homological-algebra, sheaf-theory

Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a torsion sheaf in a smooth projective scheme $X$.

Is it true that $\mathcal{Hom}(\mathcal{F}, \mathcal{O}_{X}) = 0$?

If so, where can I find the demonstration of this result?

I would appreciate any help.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Do you mean torsion with respect to $\mathcal O_X$ or with respect to $\mathbb Z$ (wikipedia only defines the latter, that's why I'm wondering) ? I assume the former, because otherwise if you take for instance everything over $\mathbb F_p$, then $\mathcal O_X$ would itself be $p$-torsion

Comment: Hi Max. Yes,  with respect to $\mathcal{O}_{X}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f : \mathcal F \to \mathcal O_X$ non-zero and $s \in F(X)$ so that the image of $s$ is not zero. Since $\mathcal F$ is torsion, there is $t \in \mathcal O_X$ so that $ts = 0$. It implies that $s$ is zero outside the locus $Z(t)$. In particular, $f(s)$ is zero outside $Z(t)$ and by density $f(s)$ is zero everywhere, a contradiction.

Comment: Hi Nicolas. Are you all right? Honestly, with all due respect, I understood nothing of your answer. I want to understand the following fact: Let $$0 \longrightarrow \mathcal{F}_{1}\longrightarrow \mathcal{F}_{2} \longrightarrow \mathcal{F}_{3} \longrightarrow \mathcal{F}_{4} \longrightarrow 0$$ be an exact sequence of sheaves in $X$.  If $\mathcal{F}_{1}$ is torsion sheaf, then taking $\text{Hom}(-, \mathcal{O}_{X})$ of this exact sequence, we have $\text{Hom}(\mathcal{F}_{1}, \mathcal{O}_{X}) = 0?$

Comment: Hi Allan. Which step you don't understand ? I'm proving that if $f \in Hom(F, O_X)$ is a morphism of $O_X$-modules and $F$ is torsion then $f = 0$. Isn't what you want ?

Comment: Hi Nicolas. I didn't understand the part: by density". thanks for attention.

Comment: If a function is zero on an open set (in the Zariski topology), it is zero everywhere.

Comment: Just so I can understand better: Zariski's not empty openings are always dense?

Comment: Yes (if $X$ is irreducible which I assumed).

Comment: Ok, Nicolas. Thank you so much for your answer.

Comment: Dear@NicolasHemelsoet, in your answer, $s$ is zero outside the locus $Z(t)$, can we deduce that $s$ is zero by density of $Z(t)$?